# Only display label per category

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
year <- as.factor(c(1999,2000,2001))
era <- c(0.4,0.6,0.7)
player_id <- as.factor(c(2,2,2))
df <- data.frame(year, era, player_id)
```

Using this data I created the following graph:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y=era, colour = player_id))+ 
 geom_line() +
 geom_text(aes(label = player_id), hjust=0.7)
```

Thing is however that I do now get a label at every datapoint. I only want to have a label at the end of each datapoint.

Any thoughts on what I should change to I get only one label?

Comment: maybe have a look at the `directlabels` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want label at end of data point. You could do this using `directlabels` library, as below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y=era, group = player_id, colour = player_id))+ 
geom_line() +
scale_colour_discrete(guide = 'none') +
scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0, 1)) +
geom_dl(aes(label = player_id), method = list(dl.combine("last.points"), cex = 0.8))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly what you want, then you can replace the `geom_text(...)` with `geom_point()`

[image]